# How do I run a binary from a Cocoa app?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm making a simple launcher for a binary so I can have it appear in my launchpad.

My initial thought was that running `system("./myProgram");` would be sufficient, but it doesn't appear to actually do anything as the terminal instance it runs doesn't stay open after running the command, immediately shutting down whatever other tasks the program did.

So my question is, is there a way for me to do this that keeps it open indefinitely?

Edit: I want my launcher to close immediately after launching the program, so it would be less than ideal to rely on something that requires it to stay open

Edit: the following all work, but only when run from xcode, when running it stand-alone it doesn't launch the program at all

```
system("open /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app myProgram");
system("open myProgram");
system("/bin/sh -c ./myProgram&");
system("./myProgram&");

NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath: @"/bin/bash"];
[task setArguments: @[@"-c", @"./myProgram"]];
[task launch];
```

`NSTask` does not give any errors, and it doesn't throw any exceptions either when the app runs

Literally every other aspect of the program works, it just won't launch, and it won't say why

Based on all the "feedback" here's what I got so far. And it still doesn't work unless I provide an absolute path (which is no good in case I want to move it later)

```
//
//  AppDelegate.m
//  DFLauncher
//
//  Created by Electric Coffee on 11/02/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Electric Coffee. All rights reserved.
//

#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@end

NSString *CURRENT_DIR;
NSString *FILE_PATH;
NSString *INIT_PATH  = @"/data/init/init.txt";
NSString *VOLUME_ON  = @"[SOUND:YES]";
NSString *VOLUME_OFF = @"[SOUND:NO]";

BOOL contains(NSString *a, NSString *b) {
    return [a rangeOfString: b].location != NSNotFound;
}

NSData *replaceString(NSString *fileContents, NSString *from, NSString *to) {
    return [[fileContents stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: from withString: to]
            dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching: (NSNotification *)aNotification {
    CURRENT_DIR = [[NSFileManager new] currentDirectoryPath]; //[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    //NSLog(@"%@", CURRENT_DIR);

    FILE_PATH = [CURRENT_DIR stringByAppendingString: INIT_PATH];
    _fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile: FILE_PATH
                                              encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                 error: NULL];
    if (contains(_fileContents, VOLUME_OFF))
        [_toggleMute setState: YES];
    if (contains(_fileContents, VOLUME_ON))
        [_toggleMute setState: NO];
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

 }

- (IBAction)playButtonClick: (id)sender {
    //system("open /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app df"); // doesn't quite work
    //system("open /Applications/df_osx/df");
    //system("/bin/sh -c /Applications/df_osx/df&");
    //system("/Applications/df_osx/df&");

    NSString *gamePath = [CURRENT_DIR stringByAppendingString: @"/df&"];

    NSTask *task = [NSTask new];
    [task setLaunchPath: @"/bin/bash"];
    [task setArguments: @[@"-c", gamePath]];
    NSError *error = task.standardError;
    [task launch];

    [NSAlert alertWithError: error];

    //[NSApp terminate: self];
}

- (IBAction)folderButtonClick: (id)sender {
    system("open .");
}

- (IBAction)quitButtonClick: (id)sender {
    [NSApp terminate: self];
}

- (IBAction)mute: (id)sender {
    NSData *result;
    NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if ([sender state] == NSOffState)
        result = replaceString(_fileContents, VOLUME_OFF, VOLUME_ON);
    else
        result = replaceString(_fileContents, VOLUME_ON, VOLUME_OFF);

    [fm createFileAtPath: FILE_PATH contents: result attributes: nil];
}
@end
```

Comment: Maybe `NSWorkspace` and/or `NSTask` can help you with this?

Comment: run it trough a shell using system("/bin/sh -c ./myProgram &");

Comment: What sort of binary is it (console or Cocoa app)?

Comment: Use NSTask, google around for code samples.

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian will it work as a fire and forget? after all I want to close the app immediately after launching the program

Comment: Have you tried a plain ole fork + exec + parent exits?

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian explain?

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian even using `NSTask` doesn't work outside of xcode

Comment: Is the cocoa app sandboxed?

Comment: @trojanfoe that might be the problem... nope it says sandbox off

Comment: OK firstly you don't want to use `system()`, but rather `NSTask`.  Secondly I would imagine the issue is the path.  `./myProgram` will only work if your app's current working directory is the same as the `myProgram` directory, and it most certainly won't be.  You don't need/want to change the app's cwd, so you need to construct a fullpath to `myProgram`.  Also if you get a failure using an API, most (all?) provide you with the reason in the form of error codes/texts.  You need to start collecting them to displaying them in your logs to help you develop your app.

Comment: @trojanfoe it's not an app I intend to distribute over the store, it WILL be in the same working directory as the program I want to use. Even when using the absolute path of the program it doesn't work. Add to that the fact that `NSTask` doesn't even do anything when I run it outside of xcode and I'm basically back to square one

Comment: Do you understand what the *Current Working Directory* is?  What error does `NSTask` give you.  Without this, no one can help you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70721/discussion-between-electric-coffee-and-trojanfoe).

Answer (score 0):

Hacky solution that works (but isn't elegant at all)

I had to replace

```
FILE_PATH = [CURRENT_DIR stringByAppendingString: INIT_PATH];
```

With

```
CURRENT_DIR = [[[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByDeletingPathExtension] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];
```

To get the correct path for the file, but it works now.